# Change dataset binding from table to stored procedure

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset

It is a windows application.
Originally I have a dataset for a dropdown menu from a table. Now I want to use a stored procedure. How to modify the process in the code?

I think that maybe the best way is to delete the the dataset and recreate a new dataset. But can we do in the designer code?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
  protected Problem_DE_DataSet(global::System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, global::System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : 
            base(info, context, false) {
        if ((this.IsBinarySerialized(info, context) == true)) {
            this.InitVars(false);
            global::System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventHandler schemaChangedHandler1 = new global::System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventHandler(this.SchemaChanged);
            this.Tables.CollectionChanged += schemaChangedHandler1;
            this.Relations.CollectionChanged += schemaChangedHandler1;
            return;
        }
        string strSchema = ((string)(info.GetValue("XmlSchema", typeof(string))));
        if ((this.DetermineSchemaSerializationMode(info, context) == global::System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema)) {
            global::System.Data.DataSet ds = new global::System.Data.DataSet();
            ds.ReadXmlSchema(new global::System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new global::System.IO.StringReader(strSchema)));
            if ((ds.Tables["Problem_DE"] != null)) {
                base.Tables.Add(new Problem_DEDataTable(ds.Tables["Problem_DE"]));
            }
            this.DataSetName = ds.DataSetName;
            this.Prefix = ds.Prefix;
            this.Namespace = ds.Namespace;
            this.Locale = ds.Locale;
            this.CaseSensitive = ds.CaseSensitive;
            this.EnforceConstraints = ds.EnforceConstraints;
            this.Merge(ds, false, global::System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Add);
            this.InitVars();
        }
        else {
            this.ReadXmlSchema(new global::System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new global::System.IO.StringReader(strSchema)));
        }
        this.GetSerializationData(info, context);
        global::System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventHandler schemaChangedHandler = new global::System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventHandler(this.SchemaChanged);
        base.Tables.CollectionChanged += schemaChangedHandler;
        this.Relations.CollectionChanged += schemaChangedHandler;
    }
```

Comment: This is generated code from the designer. I would Delete this whole function and fill my drop down menu

Comment: In your windows application what is the control ? DropDownList or ComboBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the code is easy. Implying your SQLCommand is called myCommand

- Change the `myCommand.Text` to the name of the stored procedure.
- Change the `myCommand.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

For each parameters you have in you stored procedure use this line :

- `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithCalue("@YourSQLParameter",YourValue)`

I like using `DataReaders` for this type of operation.

- `SQLDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();`

Voila ! You're StoredProcedure is executed.

Now let's say you want to add the results of the sotred procedure to the `ComboBox`.

- `while (myReader.Read())
          {
              myComboBox.Items.Add(myReader["ColumnName"].Tostring();
          }`

Basic example but i'm sure you get the point. If you need more info you can always read [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson07) it pretty much explain what you want.

Update :

It got messy with the generated code you posted up there but the approach is still the same. From what I understand you only want to read from a table using a Stored Procedure and fill a ComboBox or DropDownList with a certain field. You should try and type it from scratch in the code section without using this designer to understand how it works.

You should have something like this :

```
        //Creates a connection to your DataBase
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=YOURSERVER;Database=YOURDATABASE;User id=YOURID; Password=YOURPASSWORD");
        //Opens the connection
        myConnection.Open();
        //Creates a command (Query)
        SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        //Sets the type of query to Stored Procedure (EXEC ...)
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //The Query is set to stored procedure so (EXEC THE_NAME_OF_YOU_STOREDPROCEDURE)
        myCommand.CommandText = "THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_STOREDPROCEDURE";

        //This will add each parameter to your query (EXEC THE_NAME_OF_YOURSTOREDPROCEDURE @YOURPARAMETER
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YOURPARAMETER", THE_VALUE_OF_THE_PARAMETER);
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        //For each records returned the item from the ["YOURCOLUMN"] will be added to the comboBox
        while(myReader.Read())
        {
          myComboBox.Items.Add(myReader["YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"]);
        }
        myReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a stored procedure just gives you another another table. If you are using the dataset-designer, just create a new tableadapter and use a stored procedure as the select statement.

If this is not what you are asking for, please update your question with some code.